# Howto convert a char[] into a vector<char> in one expression (portably)

Tags: c++, string, vector

I am writing a C to C++ parser and I need a way to convert a string literal into a vector in one single expression.

I am able to do so but I am using a GCC extension:

[GCC's Statements and Declarations in Expressions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html)

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << vector<int>({1, 2, 3, 4, 5})[0] << endl;

    cout << vector<char>({'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'})[0] << endl;

    cout << ({string temp("Hello"); vector<char>(temp.begin(), temp.end());})[0] << endl;    
}
```

Is there a way to do so without using the GCC extension?

Comment: A helper function perhaps? `vector<char> to_vector(string);`

Comment: Yes of course... Please add an answer and I will vote for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out all I have to do is use a helper function:

```
template <typename T, size_t S>
    inline vector<T> to_vector(T const (& o)[S])
    {
        return vector<T>(o, o + S);
    }

int main()
{
    cout << to_vector({1, 2, 3, 4, 5})[4] << endl;

    cout << to_vector({'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'})[4] << endl;

    cout << to_vector("Hello")[4] << endl;    
}
```